# Auto generating a purchase order when a product (with quantity 0) is ordered

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

When the product has quantity on hand equal to zero, and customer orders this product, then, we need Odoo to generate a purchase order automatically for this product.

Odoo is not generating the automatic PO. We have Odoo 8.

As for an example, I created a test product. I ticked "Buy" check box, and unticked the"Make to order" check box. I added a vendor (has an address) on the product as follows:
Supplier: Old Stocks -
Delivery Lead Time: 0 -
Minimal Quantity: 1.00

I also created a reordering rule for this product:
Name: PO/8406724
Product: [9781452555508] 0.0.0.0 Would Our Legacy Survive? 
Warehouse: Amman Stock -
Location: AmmWH/Stock -
Minimum Quantity: 5.000 -
Maximum Quantity: 20.000 -
Quantity Multiple: 1.000

I made a purchase order for this product, and transferred the delivery order. The quantity on hand became 4 (less than the min. quantity in the reordering rule). Run the schedulers from Warehouse -> Run Schedulers. However, the RfQ was not created.

What should I do to get an RfQ auto-generated, when the there is sales order for a product with "Quantity on hand" equal to zero?

Thanks you :)

Comment: By the way, we have about 10 million products

Answer (score 0):

I tried on V9(sorry don't have V8), and it works perfectly.
I follow that process:
[Odoo Tuto for minimum stock rule](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/9.0/purchase/replenishment/flows/setup_stock_rule.html)
Can you try it ?

Regards,

FTK